# Filter Table using Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I need some help actually I am using Material UI & React and need to have two implementation that is

1. I need to have a Filter that filter out all the rows that is present (I need filter for each Column) Image is attached below.
2. I need a button that adds the same in the row (Image attached )

Code are as follow

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Typography,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableBody,
  Button
} from '@material-ui/core';


const Table = props => {
  const { columnHeaders, data } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer >
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow >
              {columnHeaders.map((k, index) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={k}
                  className={'product-line-tablehead '}
                  style={{
                    width: `${100 / columnHeaders.length}%`
                  }}
                >
                  {k.title}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data.map((k, index) => (
              <TableRow key={index}>
                <TableCell>
                  <Typography variant='body1'
                  >
                    {k.Product}
                  </Typography>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <Typography
                  >
                    {k.Code}
                  </Typography>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <Typography
                  >
                    {k.Branding}
                  </Typography>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align='center'>
                  <Typography
                  >
                    <img
                      src={DeleteIcon}
                    />
                    <Button                          
                    >
                      Clear
                    </Button>
                  </Typography>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

where i am getting the value and the parent component is something like this

```
 import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
    import Table from './Table';
    
    const mocklabels = [
      {
        title: 'Teacher',
        link: ''          },
      {
        title: 'Student',
        link: ''          }
    ];
    
    const columnHeaders = [
      {
        title: 'Name'
      },
      {
        title: 'Class'
      },
      {
        title: 'Gender'
      },
      {
        title: ''
      }
    ];
    const data = [
      {
        Product: 'Lorum Ipsum Dolar',
        Code: 'Lorum Ipsum Dolar',
        Branding: 'Lorum Ipsum Dolar'
      },
      {
        Product: 'Lorum Ipsum Dolar',
        Code: 'Lorum Ipsum Dolar',
        Branding: 'Lorum Ipsum Dolar'
      }
    ];
    
        
      );
    };
```

;

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Image 3

[image]

Image 4

[image]

Comment: Please clarify the scope of Filters. The image attached doesn;t show anything pertaining to the filters.

Comment: Filter must contain what ever value we have stored in it , for example Gender Male, or Person Name : Shubham so if we type Abhishek it should filter out all table rows that has Abhishek in it similar if we write Male only male get filtered out

Comment: Have a look at this sandbox and let me know if this is what you want?
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sound-5lo12z?file=/src/App.js
I'll post and explaination as the answer

Comment: Your use case is a bit odd. So I have modified the sandbox to match the requirements (or atleast what I understood). Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes it works can you explain the flow it will be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting out, whenever you want to *'filter'* an array of items in a React App based on a condition(s). Please make sure to save an original copy of the data. This is absolutely important since once the filters are removed, you'd probably want to go back to display the original data.

```
const [mainData, setMainData] = useState(data); //orignial array
const [appData, setAppData] = useState(data.slice()); //copied array that is rendered
```

With that being said, your use case requires you to toggle a filtering option on the table headers and based on which column the filter is applied to, you need to filter the items on that property.

You seemed to have used an array of columns to render the table headers, so I just added an additional property of *'key'* on each object. This property's value should match the property on the object that is rendered out as a table row.

```
const columnHeaders = [
    {
        title: "Product Name",
        key: "Product", //should match your data's object key
        value: ""
    },
    {
        title: "Product Name",
        key: "Code", //should match your data's object key
        value: ""
    },
    {
        title: "Product Name",
        key: "Branding", //should match your data's object key
        value: ""
    },
    {
        title: ""
    }
];
```

Table headers should now render like this:

```
<TableRow>
  {props.tableHeaders.map((k, index) => (
    <TableCell
      key={index}
      className={"product-line-tablehead "}
      style={{
        width: `${100 / props.tableHeaders.length}%`
      }}
    >
      {k.title ? (
        <>
          <h3>{k.title}</h3>
          {props.isSearching && (
            <Input
              value={k.value}
              onChange={(e) => {
                props.handleHeaderChange(e, index, k.key);
              }}
            />
          )}
        </>
      ) : props.isSearching ? (
        <CancelIcon
          onClick={() => {
            props.setSearching(false);
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <SearchIcon
          onClick={() => {
            props.setSearching(true);
          }}
        />
      )}
    </TableCell>
  ))}
</TableRow>
```

Next, the onChange handler `handleHeaderChange(e, index, k.key);` is responsible to trigger the filtering on the table's records. The implementation should be as follows:

```
const handleHeaderChange = (e, index, prop) => {
    
    tableHeaders[index].value = e.target.value;
    
    setTableHeaders(tableHeaders);
    
    let _newAppData = mainData.filter((f) => {
      let _condition = tableHeaders
        .filter((h) => h.value)
        .map((a) => {
          let _obj = f[a.key];
          return (
            _obj !== undefined &&
            _obj.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(a.value.toLowerCase()) >= 0
          );
        });
      return _condition.indexOf(false) >= 0 ? false : true;
    });

    setAppData(_newAppData);
};
```

So in here, we are just filtering the original data by iterating over header input values and associating to the respective object property value.
`f` is each item in the data array, `a` is each item on the header array which has `key` (that is the name of the property on `f`) and `value` that is the filter input of that column.

`_condition` is an array of boolean values and `_condition.indexOf(false) >= 0 ? false : true;` simply signifies an **AND** condition.

full code can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sound-5lo12z?file=/src/App.js:564-667

Comment: I need some changes Like the image I have updated above @Mujeeb Quereshi it will be great help if it like that

Actually I dont need any specific Search bar, or toggle bar in additional line 

What I simple need is There should be a table which has header, second row should have input fields in square shape as shown in Image above, which will ask as search filter,
later in the same row there is a function (Add Icon) if one doesnt wana search but add instead once we fill in the value it get populated to the Table, that what I wana acheive , Hope it can be modified Sir

Comment: Please check the sandbox again: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sound-5lo12z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If this works i'll add edits to the answer

Comment: Everything work Perfect thanks Sir, Just few last requirement 
1. The screen should load as the once we are seeing now (Image No 1 attached )(I have updated the json for better data flow)
2. In the Header that should act a filter (Working as expected only change is required that is the filter should only target to its column but not entire row data, 
should only filter out the column for example Name Should only filter name column)
Also Clear button should clear the filter to Black Values.
3. The Third Header should be a drop down that is Gender i.e Male or female. (Image No 2 Attached)

Comment: 4. Once I click on AddIcon a new row should be present where we are allowed to add rows once we click on save Button or icon(Image No 3 attached )
or cancel it (That should work as delete and nothing should be added)
5. Once we click on edit only Name Should be Editable as Text Field rest should be as it is.(Image No 4 attached ) And the Edit Icon will chage to save or Cancel, 
were if we save the modified value should be Saved or if we hit cancel it should remain the way it is.

Hope it works
Thanks in advace , I learned many new things too thanks you

Comment: Once the Add button is click that should also have a drop down for Adding Gender male or female as it has in filter

Comment: Lastly The Filter & the new Tab (once Clicking Add Icon) should have place holders in it Like Name for name, Class for class and Gender for gender in Opac I mean fade test 

All should be achieved from MaterialUI